# How to position views/layout programmatically in a linear layout

Tags: android

Good day, I have a requirement which i need to include a layout (actually a custom Action_bar) to an already created layout (that was done in xml) depending on which intent is being sent. i.e if intent A sends, then include the layout. if intent B sends, don't.

i have successfully added the optional layout, by doing this:

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad_linearlayout_id);

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null, true);  //
                layout.addView(view);
```

but question is, how do i make it the first view in the layout?.. Please any help will be highly appreciated as always. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you are implementing your own actionbar but if its to add a uniform UX across all version of android consider checking out http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: @slayton, i knew people will be wondering why am doing it. actually am using greendroid for it but the problem is i have tab activities that get populated from the listview, and greendroid has a different way of adding actionbar for both TabActivity and ListActivity. i end up having the actionbar display twice in the TabActivities because of the Listview.. so i had to create a custom own and use a normal Listactivity for only this particular case when the intent is not sent by the TabActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the view using an index.
For example, the first view will be index 0.

See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! funny missed that one.